# Ag-Grid edit data and sending to server

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Ag-grid on angular able to create grid fetching data from local json file.
On editing any row how to save that data and then send to server or possibly local json file ??

In short Ag-Grid how to save row data after edit and send to server on click of Submit button.
Anyone if implemented this on Javascript please comment, will try to use that on angular

Please let me know if there is any other best option apart from **ag-grid** to implement this functionality

Comment: Are you able to edit the data? Or do you need help in both editing + saving the data?

Comment: @wentjun - editing i am doing just by adding 'editable: true' attribute under each columnDefs value.
Yes any how i am able to edit the data and change it but dont know how to save the New Data respective to every row then sending to server

Comment: Just to clarify, do you only require the rows whereby the changes have been made? Or do you want to get the data from the entire grid?

Comment: @wentjun - whatever looks feasible in the end want to update that particular changed value on backend also by sending entire grid data

Comment: Hey @Olivia! Are you intending for this question to be used in reference to Angular, or AngularJS, and JavaScript or TypeScript? These are different ecosystems.

Comment: @OneLunchMan: Yes Angular + TypeScript

Comment: I the future, please be sure to check the tags on the question to reflect the technologies that are essential, not incidental to the question. Also, please read the tags being added to ensure they're accurate (example being that this question was not intended for the AngularJS or JavaScript tags)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to listen to specific changes to a particular row, you can make use of the `onCellValueChanged`, or `onRowValueChanged` event bindings when defining the ag-grid component on your component template.

```
 <ag-grid-angular 
.
.
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
(onRowValueChanged) = onRowValueChanged($event)
>
```

and on your component.ts, the `onRowValueChanged` method will be fired every time you make any changes

```
 export class YourComponent {
 private gridApi;
 private gridColumnApi;
   .
   . 
 onRowValueChanged: function(event) {
   console.log(event) // access the entire event object
   console.log(event.data) // access and print the updated row data
   const gridData = this.getAllData();
   // api call to save data

}

getAllData() {
  let rowData = [];
  this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
  return rowData;  
}

onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}
```

Comment: great onRowValueChanged attribute worked, i am getting that data in chrome console, but how to send entire grid updated data to server on click of button Submit ??

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer. You have to use the   `this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data))` to get data from all the rows in the grid. Let me know if that works?

Comment: Did you initialise Ag-grid's params api on your component?

Comment: I have updated my code. `this.gridApi` should be defined now

Comment: Glad to help! All the best!

Comment: In html use (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)". Don't use onCellValueChanged

Comment: @wentjun https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231178/angular-ag-grid-undo-selected-row-changes-on-button-click

Please help me on this

Comment: @Ruthi - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231178/angular-ag-grid-undo-selected-row-changes-on-button-click

PLease help me on this

Comment: @Olivia I will look at it today. Give me some time

Comment: Looks like someone has answered your question! I think that is the right answer for what you've posted there

Comment: @wentjun - i am trying that but its not working, comment posted is not accordance with ag-grid